# How to instantiate, initialize and populate an array in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following classes in TypeScript:

```
class bar {
    length: number;
}

class foo {
    bars: bar[] = new Array();
}
```

And then I have:

```
var ham = new foo();
ham.bars = [
    new bar() {          // <-- compiler says Expected "]" and Expected ";"
        length = 1
    }
];
```

Is there a way to do that in TypeScript?

**UPDATE**

I came up with another solution by having a set method to return itself:

```
class bar {
    length: number;

    private ht: number;
    height(h: number): bar {
        this.ht = h; return this;
    }

    constructor(len: number) {
        this.length = len;
    }
}

class foo {
    bars: bar[] = new Array();
    setBars(items: bar[]) {
        this.bars = items;
        return this;
    }
}
```

so you can initialize it as below:

```
var ham = new foo();
ham.setBars(
    [
        new bar(1).height(2),
        new bar(3)
    ]);
```

Comment: It would be really useful to have object initializers in TypeScript similar to C#. `[ {length: 1} ]` is not instance of bar but if supported, `new bar() { length = 1 }` would be instance of bar. Maybe we should make a feature suggestion for this?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

There isn't a field initialization syntax like that for objects in JavaScript or TypeScript.

Option 1:

```
class bar {
    // Makes a public field called 'length'
    constructor(public length: number) { }
}

bars = [ new bar(1) ];
```

Option 2:

```
interface bar {
    length: number;
}

bars = [ {length: 1} ];
```

Comment: to make things clearer and typesafe : `bars:bar[]=[{length:1}]`

Comment: Is there any way to do this without defining classes?

Comment: The question is about how to initialize an array in a class. There isn't a way to initialize an array in a class without using classes.

Answer (score 28):

If you really want to have named parameters plus have your objects be instances of your class, you can do the following:

```
class bar {
    constructor (options?: {length: number; height: number;}) {
        if (options) {
            this.length = options.length;
            this.height = options.height;
        }
    }
    length: number;
    height: number;
}

class foo {
    bars: bar[] = new Array();
}

var ham = new foo();
ham.bars = [
    new bar({length: 4, height: 2}),
    new bar({length: 1, height: 3})
];
```

Also [here](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/334)'s the related item on typescript issue tracker.

Comment: +1 for issue link. 
You can also make initializer values optional:

`options? : {length?: number; height?: number;}`

Answer (score 15):

A simple solution could be:

```
interface bar {
    length: number;
}

let bars: bar[];
bars = [];
```

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to 'add' additional items to a page, you may want to create an array of maps. This is how I created an **array of maps** and then added results to it:

```
import { Product } from '../models/product';

products: Array<Product>;          // Initialize the array.

[...]

let i = 0;
this.service.products( i , (result) => {

    if ( i == 0 ) {
        // Create the first element of the array.
        this.products = Array(result);
    } else { 
        // Add to the array of maps.
        this.products.push(result);
    }

});
```

Where *product.ts* look like...

```
export class Product {
    id: number;
    [...]
}
```

Comment: If you initialise the Array like this: `products: Array<Product> = [];` you don't have to do the if clause.

Answer (score 2):

An other solution:

```
interface bar {
    length: number;
}

bars = [{
  length: 1
} as bar];
```